# Optimizing sql query which has inner query

Tags: sql, performance, optimization, sql-server-2012, query-optimization

i am really sorry but just began to work on SQL I did some work on SQL before but just updates, deletes and inserts now I do need to optimize the following query which takes 7 seconds for 70 items.

One table which has line items, and another table which includes suppliers offers and also a table for warehouse information.

I do need to show line items with best 3 suppliers offer (offer 1- offer 1 name - offer 1 comment ) and also warehouse information

Could you please help me about it and teach me a way to make my queries fast.

Thank you,

```
declare @usd nvarchar(10)
declare @gbp nvarchar(10)
declare @euro nvarchar(10)

set @usd=(select top 1 KUR from _APPA_WEB_KUR WHERE CURRENCY = 'USD'  ORDER BY INCKEYNO DESC)
set @gbp=(select top 1 KUR from _APPA_WEB_KUR WHERE CURRENCY = 'GBP'  ORDER BY INCKEYNO DESC)
set @euro=(select top 1 KUR from _APPA_WEB_KUR WHERE CURRENCY = 'EURO'  ORDER BY INCKEYNO DESC)

SELECT   
    item.INCKEYNO, COMMENT, item.SIRA, item.[FILE_NUMBER], [REFERANCE_NO], 
    [GROUP_ID], [IMPA_CODE], [DESCRIPTION], [UNIT], [QTTY], 
    item.[CREATED_BY], item.[DATE], removed,
    (SELECT TOP 1 (isnull
     ((SELECT   cast(sum(STHAR_GCMIK) AS int)FROM   TBLSTHAR
    WHERE   STHAR_GCKOD = 'G' AND TBLSTHAR.STOK_KODU LIKE ('%' + item.IMPA_CODE + '%') AND sthar_htur != 'L' AND SUBE_KODU = '4'), 0) - isnull
    ((SELECT   cast(sum(STHAR_GCMIK) AS int)
    FROM   TBLSTHAR
  WHERE   STHAR_GCKOD = 'C' AND TBLSTHAR.STOK_KODU LIKE ('%' + item.IMPA_CODE + '%') AND sthar_htur != 'L' AND SUBE_KODU = '4'), 0)) AS bakiye
    FROM   TBLSTHAR) AS depo4,
      (SELECT   TOP 1 (isnull
     ((SELECT   cast(sum(STHAR_GCMIK) AS int)
 FROM  TBLSTHAR  WHERE   STHAR_GCKOD = 'G' AND TBLSTHAR.STOK_KODU LIKE ('%' + item.IMPA_CODE + '%') AND sthar_htur != 'L' AND SUBE_KODU = '2'), 0) 
                                 - isnull ((SELECT   cast(sum(STHAR_GCMIK) AS int)  FROM    TBLSTHAR WHERE    STHAR_GCKOD = 'C' AND 
                                TBLSTHAR.STOK_KODU LIKE ('%' + item.IMPA_CODE + '%') AND sthar_htur != 'L' AND SUBE_KODU = '2'), 0)) AS bakiye
    FROM   TBLSTHAR) AS depo2,
      (SELECT   TOP 1 ([SECILI_FIYAT])
    FROM   [dbo].[_APPA_SUPPLIER_OFFER_SECILI_FIYATLI_VIEW]
    WHERE   FILE_NUMBER = item.file_number AND IMPA_CODE = item.IMPA_CODE AND PRICE IS NOT NULL AND REFERANCE_NO = item.REFERANCE_NO
    ORDER BY CAST(isnull(SECILI_FIYAT, 0) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) ASC) AS OFFER1,
      (SELECT   TOP 1 SUPPLIER_ID
    FROM   [dbo].[_APPA_SUPPLIER_OFFER_SECILI_FIYATLI_VIEW]
    WHERE   FILE_NUMBER = item.file_number AND IMPA_CODE = item.IMPA_CODE AND PRICE IS NOT NULL AND REFERANCE_NO = item.REFERANCE_NO
    ORDER BY CAST(isnull(SECILI_FIYAT, 0) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) ASC) AS order1_supplier,
      (SELECT   TOP 1 COMMENT
    FROM   [dbo].[_APPA_SUPPLIER_OFFER_SECILI_FIYATLI_VIEW]
    WHERE   FILE_NUMBER = item.file_number AND IMPA_CODE = item.IMPA_CODE AND PRICE IS NOT NULL AND REFERANCE_NO = item.REFERANCE_NO
    ORDER BY CAST(isnull(SECILI_FIYAT, 0) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) ASC) AS order1_comment,
      (SELECT   dbo.trk(cari_isim)
    FROM   TBLCASABIT
    WHERE   CARI_KOD = (SELECT   SUPPLIER_ID
    FROM   (SELECT   SUPPLIER_ID, PRICE, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CAST(isnull(SECILI_FIYAT, 0) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) ASC) AS Salary_Order
    FROM   [dbo].[_APPA_SUPPLIER_OFFER_SECILI_FIYATLI_VIEW]
    WHERE   FILE_NUMBER = item.file_number AND IMPA_CODE = item.IMPA_CODE AND PRICE IS NOT NULL AND REFERANCE_NO = item.REFERANCE_NO) DT
    WHERE   DT.Salary_Order = 1)) AS offer1cari,
    (SELECT   [SECILI_FIYAT]
 FROM   (SELECT   SECILI_FIYAT, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CAST(isnull(SECILI_FIYAT, 0) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) ASC) AS Salary_Order
 FROM   [dbo].[_APPA_SUPPLIER_OFFER_SECILI_FIYATLI_VIEW]
 WHERE   FILE_NUMBER = item.file_number AND IMPA_CODE = item.IMPA_CODE AND PRICE IS NOT NULL AND REFERANCE_NO = item.REFERANCE_NO) DT
WHERE   DT.Salary_Order = 2) AS OFFER2,
    (SELECT   SUPPLIER_ID
 FROM   (SELECT   SUPPLIER_ID, SECILI_FIYAT, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CAST(isnull(SECILI_FIYAT, 0) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) ASC) AS Salary_Order
 FROM   [dbo].[_APPA_SUPPLIER_OFFER_SECILI_FIYATLI_VIEW]
 WHERE   FILE_NUMBER = item.file_number AND IMPA_CODE = item.IMPA_CODE AND PRICE IS NOT NULL AND REFERANCE_NO = item.REFERANCE_NO) DT
WHERE   DT.Salary_Order = 2) AS order2_supplier,
    (SELECT   dbo.trk(cari_isim)
 FROM   TBLCASABIT
 WHERE   CARI_KOD =(SELECT   SUPPLIER_ID
      FROM   (SELECT   SUPPLIER_ID, PRICE, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CAST(isnull(SECILI_FIYAT, 0) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) ASC) AS Salary_Order
      FROM   [dbo].[_APPA_SUPPLIER_OFFER_SECILI_FIYATLI_VIEW]
      WHERE   FILE_NUMBER = item.file_number AND IMPA_CODE = item.IMPA_CODE AND PRICE IS NOT NULL AND REFERANCE_NO = item.REFERANCE_NO) DT
 WHERE   DT.Salary_Order = 2)) AS offer2cari,
    (SELECT   COMMENT
 FROM   (SELECT   COMMENT, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CAST(isnull(SECILI_FIYAT, 0) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) ASC) AS Salary_Order
 FROM   [dbo].[_APPA_SUPPLIER_OFFER_SECILI_FIYATLI_VIEW]
 WHERE   FILE_NUMBER = item.file_number AND IMPA_CODE = item.IMPA_CODE AND PRICE IS NOT NULL AND REFERANCE_NO = item.REFERANCE_NO) DT
WHERE   DT.Salary_Order = 2) AS order2_comment,
    (SELECT   [SECILI_FIYAT]
 FROM   (SELECT   [SECILI_FIYAT], vat, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CAST(isnull(SECILI_FIYAT, 0) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) ASC) AS Salary_Order
 FROM   [dbo].[_APPA_SUPPLIER_OFFER_SECILI_FIYATLI_VIEW]
 WHERE   FILE_NUMBER = item.file_number AND IMPA_CODE = item.IMPA_CODE AND PRICE IS NOT NULL AND REFERANCE_NO = item.REFERANCE_NO) DT
WHERE   DT.Salary_Order = 3) AS OFFER3,
    (SELECT   SUPPLIER_ID
 FROM   (SELECT   SUPPLIER_ID, SECILI_FIYAT, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CAST(isnull(SECILI_FIYAT, 0) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) ASC) AS Salary_Order
 FROM   [dbo].[_APPA_SUPPLIER_OFFER_SECILI_FIYATLI_VIEW]
 WHERE   FILE_NUMBER = item.file_number AND IMPA_CODE = item.IMPA_CODE AND PRICE IS NOT NULL AND REFERANCE_NO = item.REFERANCE_NO) DT
WHERE   DT.Salary_Order = 3) AS order3_supplier,
    (SELECT   dbo.trk(cari_isim)
 FROM   TBLCASABIT
 WHERE   CARI_KOD =(SELECT   SUPPLIER_ID
      FROM   (SELECT   SUPPLIER_ID, SECILI_FIYAT, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CAST(isnull(SECILI_FIYAT, 0) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) ASC) AS Salary_Order
      FROM   [dbo].[_APPA_SUPPLIER_OFFER_SECILI_FIYATLI_VIEW]
      WHERE   FILE_NUMBER = item.file_number AND IMPA_CODE = item.IMPA_CODE AND PRICE IS NOT NULL AND REFERANCE_NO = item.REFERANCE_NO) DT
 WHERE   DT.Salary_Order = 3)) AS offer3cari,
    (SELECT   COMMENT
 FROM   (SELECT   COMMENT, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CAST(isnull(SECILI_FIYAT, 0) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) ASC) AS Salary_Order
 FROM   [dbo].[_APPA_SUPPLIER_OFFER_SECILI_FIYATLI_VIEW]
 WHERE   FILE_NUMBER = item.file_number AND IMPA_CODE = item.IMPA_CODE AND PRICE IS NOT NULL AND REFERANCE_NO = item.REFERANCE_NO) DT
WHERE   DT.Salary_Order = 3) AS order3_comment, @euro AS EURO, @gbp AS GBP, @usd AS USD, mas.CURRENCY, 
'0' depo4_fiyat,'0' depo2_fiyat, item.price, item.supplier
FROM   [dbo].[_APPA_WEB_PURCHASE_OFFER_LINE_ITEMS_2] item   LEFT OUTER JOIN
  dbo._APPA_WEB_PURCHASE_OFFER_MASTER AS mas ON mas.FILE_NUMBER = item.FILE_NUMBER 
WHERE    (item.removed != 1 OR
  item.removed IS NULL)
```

Comment: before starting with complex  query should be  better learn properly sql ..starting with simple query and join .....  you are using SQL in wrong way ..

Comment: could you please show me where are my mistakes and how could i fix them.

Comment: You have several improper use of sql ..the most relevant is a sistematic use of subselect instead of proper  join ..

Comment: but i could not manage to use join about getting 3 rows from a table and show them as column in my view,
  _APPA_SUPPLIER_OFFER_SECILI_FIYATLI_VIEW is my table which has suppliers offers for each item and i need to get these offers as column in my main view

Comment: You can make simplified schema based on Your real case, but with widely meaningfull names like Person.Age instead of TBLSTHAR.STOK_KODU and only necessary amount of properties. Provide table definitions, provide sample data and expected result. Now You can hope to get query that is adequate to what You need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is quite difficult to read. I did my best to refactor accurately, but I don't have any way to check. So here it is:

```
;WITH line_items AS (
      -- Read all the lines that we will need

       SELECT *
       FROM [dbo].[_APPA_WEB_PURCHASE_OFFER_LINE_ITEMS_2] item
       WHERE COALESCE(item.removed,0) != 1

),
suppliers AS (
      -- Get a ranked list of supplier, offers and comments

       SELECT v.COMMENT,
            v.SUPPLIER_ID,
            v.[SECILI_FIYAT],
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CAST(isnull(v.SECILI_FIYAT, 0) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) ASC) AS Salary_Order,
            v.FILE_NUMBER,
            v.IMPA_CODE,
            v.REFERANCE_NO,
            dbo.trk(b.cari_isim) AS cari
       FROM [dbo].[_APPA_SUPPLIER_OFFER_SECILI_FIYATLI_VIEW] v
          INNER JOIN line_items item
             ON v.FILE_NUMBER = item.file_number
               AND v.IMPA_CODE = item.IMPA_CODE
               AND v.REFERANCE_NO = item.REFERANCE_NO
          INNER JOIN TBLCASABIT b
             ON b.CARI_KOD = v.SUPPLIER_ID
       WHERE v.PRICE IS NOT NULL
),
 t_STHAR AS (
       SELECT     
            CAST(    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN st.SUBE_KODU = '2' AND st.STHAR_GCKOD = 'G' THEN st.STHAR_GCMIK ELSE 0 END),0) - 
                    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN st.SUBE_KODU = '2' AND st.STHAR_GCKOD = 'C' THEN st.STHAR_GCMIK ELSE 0 END),0)  AS INT) AS depo2,

            CAST(    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN st.SUBE_KODU = '4' AND st.STHAR_GCKOD = 'G' THEN st.STHAR_GCMIK ELSE 0 END),0) - 
                    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN st.SUBE_KODU = '4' AND st.STHAR_GCKOD = 'C' THEN st.STHAR_GCMIK ELSE 0 END),0)  AS INT) AS depo4
       FROM TBLSTHAR
       WHERE STHAR_HTUR != 'L'
       AND EXISTS (
          SELECT 1
          FROM line_items
          WHERE STOK_KODU LIKE('%'+item.IMPA_CODE+'%')
       )
)

SELECT item.INCKEYNO,
       COMMENT,
       item.SIRA,
       item.[FILE_NUMBER],
       [REFERANCE_NO],
       [GROUP_ID],
       [IMPA_CODE],
       [DESCRIPTION],
       [UNIT],
       [QTTY],
       item.[CREATED_BY],
       item.[DATE],
       removed,

      st.depo2,
      st.depo4,

      -- Use (JOIN, MAX, GROUP BY) method to transpose rows to columns
      MAX(CASE WHEN s.Salary_Order = 1 THEN s.[SECILI_FIYAT] END) AS OFFER1,
      MAX(CASE WHEN s.Salary_Order = 1 THEN s.SUPPLIER_ID END) AS order1_supplier,
      MAX(CASE WHEN s.Salary_Order = 1 THEN s.cari END) AS offer1cari,
      MAX(CASE WHEN s.Salary_Order = 1 THEN s.COMMENT END) AS order1_comment,

      MAX(CASE WHEN s.Salary_Order = 2 THEN s.[SECILI_FIYAT] END) AS OFFER1,
      MAX(CASE WHEN s.Salary_Order = 2 THEN s.SUPPLIER_ID END) AS order2_supplier,
      MAX(CASE WHEN s.Salary_Order = 2 THEN s.cari END) AS offer2cari,
      MAX(CASE WHEN s.Salary_Order = 2 THEN s.COMMENT END) AS order2_comment,

      MAX(CASE WHEN s.Salary_Order = 3 THEN s.[SECILI_FIYAT] END) AS OFFER3,
      MAX(CASE WHEN s.Salary_Order = 3 THEN s.SUPPLIER_ID END) AS order3_supplier,
      MAX(CASE WHEN s.Salary_Order = 3 THEN s.cari END) AS offer3cari, ---
      MAX(CASE WHEN s.Salary_Order = 3 THEN s.COMMENT END) AS order3_comment,

       @euro AS EURO,
       @gbp AS GBP,
       @usd AS USD,
       mas.CURRENCY,
       '0' depo4_fiyat,
       '0' depo2_fiyat,
       item.price,
       item.supplier
FROM line_items item
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo._APPA_WEB_PURCHASE_OFFER_MASTER mas
       ON mas.FILE_NUMBER = item.FILE_NUMBER
    LEFT JOIN suppliers s
       ON item.FILE_NUMBER = s.FILE_NUMBER
       AND item.IMPA_CODE = s.IMPA_CODE
       AND item.REFERANCE_NO = s.REFERANCE_NO
    CROSS APPLY t_STHAR st
GROUP BY item.INCKEYNO,
       COMMENT,
       item.SIRA,
       item.[FILE_NUMBER],
       [REFERANCE_NO],
       [GROUP_ID],
       [IMPA_CODE],
       [DESCRIPTION],
       [UNIT],
       [QTTY],
       item.[CREATED_BY],
       item.[DATE],
       removed,
      st.depo2,
      st.depo4,
       mas.CURRENCY,
       item.price,
       item.supplier
;
```

Answer (score 0):

I do have an table which includes suppliers offer

> supplier_id , file_no , referance_no, item_id,comment

and i have a master table which has line item informations;

> item_id, file_no, referance_no ... etc

i do need to get best 3 supplier offer (order by price ) and supplier information supplier_id, price, comment  and i do need to add these 9 cells to my master table

> i want to see my view like ;

```
item_id, file_no, referance_no ...+ 
offer1_price, offer1_comment, offer1_supplier_id,
offer2_price, offer2_comment, offer2_supplier_id,
offer3_price, offer3_comment, offer3_supplier_id,
```

> keys are item_id,file_no and referance_no